# Use javascript to choose local javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've got two separate .js files and depending on the choice that the user makes on the form in the select tag, I want the .js file specific to the user request to be used on the html page.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.getElementById('analyses').value == 'distance'){

 <script src="/static/analysis.js"></script>

    }else{
 <script src="/static/another.js"></script>
    }
   });
</script>
```

The html form:

```
<form id="eventForm">            
     <select name="event" id="abc">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Event</option>
        <option value="US">US</option>
        <option value="UK">UK</option>
        <option value="Fr">France</option> 
     </select>             

     <select name="analysis" id="analyses">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Analysis</option>
        <option value="distance">distance</option>
        <option value="other">other</option>
     </select>

    <input type="submit" id="open" onclick="heading()" value="Start Analysis"/>
```

Presently it just runs the /static/analysis.js file, regardless of the user selection.

Thanks

EDIT:

```
<script>

function loadScript(path) {
    var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', path);
    head.appendChild(script);
}


$(document).ready(function(){
if (document.getElementById('analyses').value == 'distance'){

loadScript("/static/analysis.js");

}else{
loadScript("/static/analysisfdfdf.js");
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can't just put `else { <script> }` you need to use `else { document.write('<script...>'); }`

Comment: How can the user make a selection if you run the code as soon as the document is ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to load other JS files dynamically

```
function loadScript(path) {
    var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', path);
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Usage:

```
loadScript("/static/analysis.js");
```

Remember that the script will be asynchronously loaded so you can't assume that a script is loaded after that line. You would need the loaded script to perform a `callback` as a ready notification

Comment: Thanks I tried it as you suggested and i've updated the original question with the function but it gives ne a 405 error now.

Comment: do you get the same error if you load that url directly into the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuerys **getScript()** - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

So, when the user makes their selection you simply load in the relevant js file

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to load only one of the scripts? You could create two JavaScript functions, each containing the code from the relevant script, and execute whichever one corresponds to the user selection.

There's no reason they couldn't be defined in two separate .js files, as long as you include both of them in your html.

That seems like a simpler way to execute specific code without having to worry about loading in code dynamically.

Comment: So, you mean for each separate script just wrap it up into a large function, but load from both from one file?